# elFinder - How to open/show specific folder from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elfinder

How can I show a specific folder list while opening elFinder.

I tried as follow, but didn't work.

```
$opts = array(
    // 'debug' => true,
    'roots' => [
                [
            'driver' => 'Flysystem',
            'alias' => 'File Storage',
            'filesystem' => $filesystem,
            'path'   => $aws_url .'/folder1/folder2/folder3/',
            'startPath' => $aws_url .'/folder1/folder2/folder3',
            'URL' => $aws_url ,

            'tmbURL' => 'self'
        ]
    ]
);
// Trying to set Folder3 as root folder
```

Will really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: You can override` ElfinderController showConnector()` method.

Comment: @lovecoding-laravel I am not that good with PHP, can you give me some heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,You can override this method.

```
Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController::showConnector()
```

To override this, you can register in`AppServiceProvider`  like this.

```
$this->app->singleton(
       'Barryvdh\Elfinder\ElfinderController',
       'App\CustomElfinderProvider'
);
```

And in `App\CustomElfinderProvider`, you just copy all from `ElfinderController::showConnector()`, and change some path there.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your *code* to:

```
'path'   => 'folder1/folder2/folder3/',
```